# UPS WSDL/C# Sample Compile Error

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, ups

I have a C# ASP.NET that site I am trying to add UPS quoting to.  I used the code from the sample and have imported the included WSDL, all of the objects map out properly to the wsdl except the `RateService` class.

[This is the code sample and WSDL that I am working from](http://delta.djdmarketing.com/PACKAGEWebServices.zip).

This is the code snippet that has an error:

```
RateService rate = new RateService();
RateRequest rateRequest = new RateRequest();
UPSSecurity upss = new UPSSecurity();
```

The compile error is that `RateService` is not found.

I am pretty sure the WSDL is importing because the rest of the classes compile just fine.  Did UPS change their API since the sample?  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Your zip file is invalid / corrupted / not a zip.

Comment: Good call...fixed the link

Comment: You don't have to *guess* - just look at the classes MSVS auto-generated when you added the reference (imported the WSD??L), and look at the WSDL itself!!!!  Does it have "RateService()"?  Do you see "RateService" as an operation in the WSDL???  If it's in the WSDL, but not in your *.cs, then try re-adding the reference.  If it's not in the WSDL, then your example is bogus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WSDL file has this block:

```
<wsdl:service name="RateService">
    <wsdl:port name="RatePort" binding="tns:RateBinding">
        <!-- Production URL -->
            <!-- <soap:address location="https://onlinetools.ups.com/webservices/Rate"/> -->
            <!-- CIE (Customer Integration Environment) URL -->
            <soap:address location="https://wwwcie.ups.com/webservices/Rate"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

It looks like the `RateService` serice is defined. Are you sure it imported correctly?

The sample code (in your zip) also shows the generated web reference - it has a `RateService` class.

To add this reference to your project, go to `Add Service Reference`, select `Advanced` on the botton of the dialog and then select `Add Web Reference` on the bottom of the second dialog. Enter the URL to the WSDL file and then add the reference.

Make sure you add the correct `using` statements to your code files to use the types from the WSDL.

(This is both for VS 2008 and VS 2010.)

Comment: I used add service reference and gave it the path to the wsdl

Comment: @box86rowh Updated my answer with the steps to follow to add the reference. The reference and your 3-line sample above compiles fine if you follow those steps.

Comment: turns out i was importing the dang wsdl wrong...thanks very much for the help

Comment: @box86rowh You're very welcome. I'm glad it worked out - I hate it when I run into things like this. :)

Comment: Please - *please* familiarize yourself with the contents of the WSDL, and how it maps to the auto-generated classes C# creates.  And please consider using .Net 3.0++ "Service references" instead of the older .Net --2.0 "Web references" whenever possible.  IMHO...